# How can I position a rotated image within a container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using CSS3, HTML (and javascript/jquery if needed), I need to rotate an image 90/270 degrees and have it position to fill its parent div/container. Sounds simple, but when images are rotated, there positioning changes and I can't figure out how or why.

Here is a jsFiddle to explain - http://jsfiddle.net/UPGkU/2/ - I just want the blue logo to be position exactly within the red div.

Of course, I could use specific offsets, but if a different image is used, those offsets change, so I really want to find a generic solution.

Any help would be fantastic, thanks!

Comment: i think you want this http://jsfiddle.net/UPGkU/5/

Answer (score 9):

You need to set a [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-origin) - in this scenario, a point around which the image gets rotated.

```
#image {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; //initially 50% 50%
  margin-left: 100%;
}
```

[90deg fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/UPGkU/6/)  /  [270deg fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/UPGkU/9/)

***Update:***

The challenge with the latter is that we can't really modify `transform-origin` as its position is relative to the *not yet transformed* element and we can't just set `margin-top:100%` since margin values (even vertical ones) are calculated as [a percentage always relative to the *width* of the containing block](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/UPGkU/6/). The following code should work:

```
#image {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  position:relative;
  top:100%;
}
```

Comment: I prefer your solution : +1. It is not image-size dependent

Comment: +1. Perhaps it's also worth mentioning that the initial value for `transform-origin` is `50% 50%`.

Comment: ah, but if I rotate it 270 degrees the solution break. Is there a way that it can fit inside the red container if rotated 90 or 270 degrees? If the answer is 'no', that is fine!

Answer (score 2):

try with

```
#image {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    position : relative;
    top      : -50px;
}
```

​

Comment: +1, if only this could be made more generic (i.e. without relying on dimensions in pixels)

Answer (score 0):

Hi now **used** to this **css**  used **position**

```
#wrapper {
    width:50px;
    height:150px;
    border:2px solid red;
    position:relative;
}
#image {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    position:absolute;
    left:-49px;
    top:50px;
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UPGkU/5/)***