# CSS rotate image, keep it always aligned to left top corner

Tags: jquery, html, css, rotation, css-transforms

I am working on online designer, where you can rotate your images and I am changing server side rotation for CSS version, but its not working correctly (image is not being aligned at all).

I tried `translateX translateY`, also `transform-origin`, wrappers, `position: absolute` with `position:relative` and so on, but nothing worked.

Here is sample code (you can see that image is being cut and moved away.

https://jsfiddle.net/st1xnzqz/2/

```js
$("#left").on("click", function () {
    var rotation = $(".rotator").attr("data-rotate");
    if (rotation == 270) {
        rotation = 0;
    } else {
        rotation = parseInt(rotation) + 90;
    }
    if (rotation === 270 || rotation === 90) {
        $('.rotator').css("height", 600);
    } else {
        $('.rotator').css("height", 390);
    }
    $(".rotator").attr("data-rotate", rotation);
    $(".rotator img").css("transform", "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)");
});

$("#right").on("click", function () {
    var rotation = $(".rotator").attr("data-rotate");
    if (rotation == 0) {
        rotation = 270;
    } else {
        rotation = parseInt(rotation) - 90;
    }
    if (rotation === 270 || rotation === 90) {
        $('.rotator').css("height", 600);
    } else {
        $('.rotator').css("height", 390);
    }
    $(".rotator").attr("data-rotate", rotation);
    $(".rotator img").css("transform", "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)");
});
```

```css
#left, #right {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.rotator {
    height: 390px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="controls">
    <div id="left">Rotate left</div>
    <div id="right">Rotate Right</div>
</div>
<div class="rotator" data-rotate="0">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/390/any" />
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

---

**WORKING* CODE:**

Thanks to @areim for finding the second topic (I did not find it, and I was searching since yesterday). Now its working well. The code looks just stupid with all the CSS, but it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/st1xnzqz/3/

```js
$("#left").on("click", function () {
    var rotation = $(".rotator").attr("data-rotate");
    if (rotation == 270) {
        rotation = 0;
    } else {
        rotation = parseInt(rotation) + 90;
    }
    if (rotation === 270) {
        $('.rotator').css({
            "height": "600",
            "width": "390"
        });
        $(".rotator img").css({
            "margin-left": "0",
            "top": "100%",
            "transform-origin": "0 0"
        });
    } else if (rotation === 90) {
        $('.rotator').css({
            "height": "600",
            "width": "390"
        });
        $(".rotator img").css({
            "margin-left": "100%",
            "top": "0",
            "transform-origin": "0 0"
        });
    } else {
        $('.rotator').css({
            "height": "390",
            "width": "600"
        });
        $(".rotator img").css({
            "margin-left": "0",
            "top": "0",
            "transform-origin": ""
        });
    }
    $(".rotator").attr("data-rotate", rotation);
    $(".rotator img").css("transform", "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)");
});

$("#right").on("click", function () {
    var rotation = $(".rotator").attr("data-rotate");
    if (rotation == 0) {
        rotation = 270;
    } else {
        rotation = parseInt(rotation) - 90;
    }
    if (rotation === 270) {
        $('.rotator').css({
            "height": "600",
            "width": "390"
        });
        $(".rotator img").css({
            "margin-left": "0",
            "top": "100%",
            "transform-origin": "0 0"
        });
    } else if (rotation === 90) {
        $('.rotator').css({
            "height": "600",
            "width": "390"
        });
        $(".rotator img").css({
            "margin-left": "100%",
            "top": "0",
            "transform-origin": "0 0"
        });
    } else {
        $('.rotator').css({
            "height": "390",
            "width": "600"
        });
        $(".rotator img").css({
            "margin-left": "0",
            "top": "0",
            "transform-origin": ""
        });
    }
    $(".rotator").attr("data-rotate", rotation);
    $(".rotator img").css("transform", "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)");
});
```

```css
#left, #right {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.rotator {
    width: 600px;
    height: 390px;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}
.rotator img {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="controls">
    <div id="left">Rotate left</div>
    <div id="right">Rotate Right</div>
</div>
<div class="rotator" data-rotate="0">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/390/any" />
</div>
```

- There are still ton of bugs with this, but the main rotation works with this code pretty well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I position a rotated image within a container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366458/how-can-i-position-a-rotated-image-within-a-container)

Comment: @areim hmm, thank Im trying that one right now and its still bugging out... AAAAND its working now... I was googling for it since yesterday and was not able to find that damn topic.... Thanks.